# Excel chart with only x axis and empty space beetween points

Tags: excel, charts

I need to draw Excel chart with only x axis and empty space between the points.

For example I will have points on x axis (1,3), (5,8), (9,10)

The line should go from 1-3 then empty then line from 5-8 then empty then line from 9,10

I tried something with Scatter graph but didn't manage to do it.

Basic-lay Y axis can exist but I will always use the same value

Any ides?

Here is screenshot to get the idea. It is not connected to mentioned points

[Chart Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7pRk.png)

In chart example points would be (3,5) , (7,8)

Comment: Can you draw what you want and post a screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

First in your data, add a empty row in your data where you want the space (row 10 in my example).

Choose a "Scatter plot with Straight Lines and Markers"

[image]

Then format your axis (right click on x-axis and choose format axis) to "Units" -> "Major": 1.

Notice how my empty space creates a gap between the two series (5,8) and (9,10).

[image]